# Java: Cannot Find Symbol - Inheriting Methods

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to use a method that I have in another class file. However, I get an error.

Error: cannot find symbol
 Symbol: variable dPUSe
 Location: class StatInput

This is in my main class:

```
DeterminePoints dPUse = new DeterminePoints();
if(choice == 1){
 dPUse.topLane(); 
}
```

The method topLane() is an empty one in another class file that I have in the same folder:

```
public void topLane(){
}
```

But I am getting the error stated above.

Answer (score 2):

Your capitalization is off between your code and your error message:

Error Message: `Symbol: variable dPUSe`

Code: `DeterminePoints dPUse`

Do you use the one with the capital S anywhere?  Because you haven't defined that one, so Java doesn't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a instance of that class or make this class extend that class to use the method from that class,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere you use, dPUSe, not dPUse